# Multiple definition and header-only libraries

Tags: c, include, multiple-definition-error

I have a C program with several c and h files. I decided to make one part of the program 'header-only' so I moved the code from c to h. Now I'm getting multiples definition problems and I have no idea why. e.g.:

```
main.c includes utils.h
vector.c includes utils.h
```

I moved everything in utils.c to utils.h (and of course removed utils.c from the project). utils.h starts with

```
#ifndef UTILS_H_
#define UTILS_H_

// and end with:
#endif
```

To be sure my guard was unique I tried changing it (e.g.: UTILS718171_H_) but it doesn't work.

Still, the compiler complains:

```
/tmp/ccOE6i1l.o: In function `compare_int':
ivector.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `compare_int'
/tmp/ccwjCVGi.o:main.c:(.text+0x660): first defined here
/tmp/ccOE6i1l.o: In function `compare_int2':
ivector.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `compare_int2'
/tmp/ccwjCVGi.o:main.c:(.text+0x6e0): first defined here
/tmp/ccOE6i1l.o: In function `matrix_alloc':
ivector.c:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of `matrix_alloc'
/tmp/ccwjCVGi.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
...
```

The problem might be something like: all c files are compiled and get their own version of the code and then at linkage it causes problem, but I have honestly no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: try to post utils.h. Remember to put only prototypes or constants inside utils.h

Comment: question [2174657](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174657/when-are-header-only-libraries-acceptable) has some info about when/how to use header-only libraries.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you define your variables inside your header file and include the header in several c files, you are bound to get multiple definitions error because you break the **One definition rule(ODR)**, which states that there should be only one definition in one **Translation Unit**(header files + source file).

**Solution is:**
You should define the entities you get Multiple definition errors for only once.
**For Functions:**
Declare the function prototypes in header file(which you include in other source files) and define the function in *one and only one* source file.
**For Global variables:**
You declare the variable extern in header file(which you include in other source files) and then define the variable in *one and only one* source file.

Comment: Why am I able to define a member function in a class header? I know that implies that the function will be inlined, but is that the only reason?

Comment: Although this answer was accepted, it is not the right answer to this question because it misses the entire point: the OP wishes to use a header-only file, with all declarations and definitions in the same file. There are legitimate reasons why this may be necessary in the Arduino environment, even without the Arduino IDE. This answer merely states that you should NOT use header-only files. There are three ways to get around the multiple definition problem, each with different implications and costs. IMO the applicable solution here would be to declare any non-member functions as inline.

Comment: why `ifndef` does not work to avoid multiple definitions of the variables?

Comment: @rsonx because the header gets included once, but by multiple source files, each building its own object file. each one includes the header only once, but there is more then one object file. the multiple definitions only come to light when trying to link them together.

Answer (score 14):

You are missing the point of #ifndef _FOO_H / #define _FOO_H / #endif construct.  That only protects against multiple inclusions in ONE file. For example they protect against this:

foo.h:

```
  #ifndef _FOO_H 
  #define _FOO_H

  /* some C stuff here */

  #endif /* _FOO_H */
```

foo.c:

```
   #include <foo.h>
   #include <bar.h>
   ...
```

bar.h:

```
   #include <foo.h>
   ...
```

note that foo.c and bar.h both include foo.h; here the #ifdef _FOO_H / #define _FOO_H / #endif protects against that double inclusion in foo.c ( the foo.h included in bar.h doesn't redefine stuff )

#### Now the next part.

Why would you move function implementation from utils.c to utils.h? Also why did you decide to make it "header-only" ?

You can, depending on whether your compiler supports `static inline` functions do this; but even then it's NOT recommended, as more than likely, it  will make your program unnecessarily bloated because chances are your util functions are quite complex and cannot be inlined anyways.

So change it back to utils.c and utils.h construct that you had before which, i presume, WAS working and enjoy the software.

Comment: @Jeff Kelley: thanks for the edit :) writing stuff out on dark terminals without glasses on is hard.

Answer (score 6):

If you indend for the `utils.h` functions to be "copied" into each place where it is used, just use `static` functions in the header. (`static inline` in C99)

Answer (score 5):

You're violating the One-Definition-Rule. Each function must be defined precisely *once*, while you end up defining it *in each translation unit*.

You simply *cannot* do something like this:

```
// header.h
void foo() { }

// file1.c
#include "header.h"

// file2.c
#include "header.h"
```

The only real solution is to *declare* `void foo();` in the header and *define* it once only (usually in a dedicated `foo.c`). The same goes for global variables, which should be declared as `extern` in the header and defined in the source file.

Include guards have nothing to do with this. They only serve to prevent recursive self-inclusion or redundant multiple inclusion *within one translation unit*.