# include .h of c files causes strange "multiple definition" errors?

Tags: c++, c, include, multiple-definition-error

I work on a project which contains both `c` source files and `c++` ones.
I use code like :

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "init.h"
    #include "ParameterGet.h"//ParameterGet.c exists
}
```

to include c files.

But I got a `.h` files of c which has no `.c` file.
And it causes(as I think) many errors of :

```
multiple definition of `PeriodicFaultReport'
multiple definition of `FaultActiveEventReport'
multiple definition of `FaultInactiveEventReport'
multiple definition of `FaultLatchEventReport'
```

where `PeriodicFaultReport`,`FaultActiveEventReport`,`FaultInactiveEventReport`,`FaultLatchEventReport` are all declared in `"DataStruct.h"` and this file has no `.c` file with it.

Besides I notice that `PeriodicFaultReport`,`FaultActiveEventReport`,`FaultInactiveEventReport`,`FaultLatchEventReport` are all `global variables`.
**[IMPORTANT]**

Content relative in `"DataStruct.h"` of `c`:

```
struct  OptionalString PeriodicFaultReport;

struct  FaultActiveEventReportSet
{
    BOOL     Flag;
    UINT8    Type ;
    UINT32   Length;
    struct   Optional...  Report...[2];

}FaultActiveEventReport;

struct  FaultInactiveEventReportSet
{
    BOOL     Flag;
    UINT8    Type ;
    UINT32   Length  ;
    struct  Optional... Faultt...;

}FaultInactiveEventReport;

struct  FaultLatchEventReportSet
{
    BOOL     Flag;
    UINT8    Type ;
    UINT32   Length  ;
    struct  OptionalInteger  FaultID[2];

}FaultLatchEventReport;
```

I know there may be an answer like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201944/multiple-definition-and-header-only-librairies?lq=1)
But it is not right:
I get all the files from a `c` project, and there, `"DataStruct.h"` are included multiple times in other .h files, and it has no problem.
(The `c` project is in `VS2008`, which may be the reason of no problems)
But Is this true, `VS` helps to this and break the `c` standard?

Comment: Are you sure those `struct`s weren't meant to be `typedef struct`s?

Comment: @FatalError, no, surely.

Comment: To explain FatalError's question - `struct X { ... } X;` defined a structure `X` and a variable/object of that type also called `X`... that's why including the header multiple times results in multiple definitions of the variable. If it were a `typedef`, it would meant that `X` can be used as a shorthand for `struct X`... legal in C++ anyway - can't remember for C. Separately, do you have any reason to think that this code's not broken? Someone might have written a program that only included it once, and not noticed the issue. To fix, make the vars in .h `extern` and create a DataStruct.c.

Comment: Thanks Lynn.  Rubby - looking at your deleted answer - 'I get all the files from a c project, and there, "DataStruct.h" are included multiple times in other .h files, and it has no problem.' - as long as there are `#ifndef #endif` include guards or `#pragma once`, including multiple times will work if done from a *single* translation unit, but not from multiple translation units.  (A translation unit is basically the code used to generate a single object output; the error would occur when linking multiple objects each defining the variables).

Comment: I'd all-but-guarantee FatalError is correct, especially if those are in a header file. Make sure your headers are guard-fenced as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig, #ifndef __DATASTRUCT_H
#define __DATASTRUCT_H#endif

Comment: @Rubby Please update your code with those, so that we know you're applying them correctly...

Comment: Don't include C files in C++ projects. Compile them as C, and link the resulting object code to your C++ projects. There are numerous reasons for this, which I don't care to elaborate upon here. If you want answers, search for questions like "Why shouldn't I cast malloc?" and "Why does the `%` operator function differently in C++ than it does in C?". When configured to compile as C, VS2008s compiler still won't compile C99 code let alone C11 code. You are using a C++ compiler to compile C, but it can't compile valid C code written almost fifteen years ago.