# Double inclusion and headers only library stbi_image

Tags: c++, c++11, header, inclusion, header-only

I have a main.cpp including a.h (that has its own a.cpp)
a.h includes the header only library "stbi_image.h" as such:

```
#ifndef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#endif
```

(https://github.com/nothings/stb)

*.cpp includes its own *.h with the use of #pragma once

But I still get:

> LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found LNK2005 stb-failure
>   reason already defined in a.obj file = main.obj ... and a bunch of
>   others

It seems right to me, but as I understand in this question:
[Multiple definition and header-only libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201944/multiple-definition-and-header-only-libraries)

Maybe I should add inline/static to the stb_image.h function I need ?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you note the doc near the top of `stb_image.h`. As I understand this: You should include `stb_image.h` in `a.cpp` with pre-`#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` and in `main.cpp` (and anywhere else) without. (This shall probably grant that definitions are done only once otherwise you could get the link issues you actually have now.)

Comment: The comment above worked for me, this should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: I should read the documentation really. This solution perfectly works!

Answer (score 11):

1. Maybe I should add inline/static to the stb_image.h function I need ?

No, you already have a way to declare 'stb_image functions' as static or as extern:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_STATIC
```

2. Am I doing something wrong ?
   Yes, you compile 'stb_image' twice, each time you include 'stb_image.h'
   So, the whole design could be:

**Image.h:**

```
#ifndef _IMAGE_H_
#define _IMAGE_H_

Class Image.h {
public:
    Image() : _imgData(NULL) {}
    virtual ~Image();
    ...
    void loadf(...);
    ...

    unsigned char* getData() const { return _imgData; }
protected:
    unsigned char* _imgData;
};
#endif
```

**Image.cpp:**

```
#include "Image.h"

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION   // use of stb functions once and for all
#include "stb_image.h"

Image::~Image()
{ 
    if ( _imgData ) 
        stbi_image_free(_imgData); 
}

void Image::load(...) {
    _imgData = stbi_load(...);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Image.h" // as you see, main.cpp do not know anything about stb stuff

int main() {
    Image* img = new Image();  // this is my 'wrapper' to stb functions
    img->load(...);

    myTexture(img->getData(), ...);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `#ifndef` i could also use `#pragma once`, right?

Comment: @TheBaum: `#pragma` is a compiler feature and could vary from compilers to compilers. I never use it myself. I think you should avoid this.

Comment: what if I need 2 libs all of them used stb_img? But  these 2 is what I needed as thirdparty?