# Problem when using assimp library together with stb image

Tags: c++, image, cmake, dependencies, libraries

When I try to use [Assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) together with [stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb.git) it says that some functions are already defined and it will not link.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(TestProject)

add_executable(TestProject "main.cpp")

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
add_subdirectory("vendor/assimp")

target_include_directories(TestProject PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/stb")
target_include_directories(TestProject PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/assimp/include")
target_include_directories(TestProject PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/assimp/include")

target_link_libraries(TestProject PUBLIC assimp)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "assimp/Importer.hpp"
#include "assimp/scene.h"
#include "assimp/postprocess.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    uint8_t* data = stbi_load("image.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

    Assimp::Importer importer;

    stbi_image_free(data);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

This is the output I got from this. It seems like a few functions from the stb file could not be linked correctly.

```
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_from_memory already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_from_callbacks already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_from_file already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_gif_from_memory already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_16_from_memory already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_16_from_callbacks already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_16 already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_load_from_file_16 already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_loadf_from_memory already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_loadf_from_callbacks already defined in main.obj
4>assimp-vc142-mtd.lib(PbrtExporter.obj) : error LNK2005: stbi_loadf already defined in main.obj
...
```

I'm building from the source files.

Comment: I want to use the source to stay always updated.

Comment: Now that I see the errors I think this is related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348798/double-inclusion-and-headers-only-library-stbi-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348798/double-inclusion-and-headers-only-library-stbi-image)

Comment: My guess is you want to put `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` before the  assimp includes in your main.cpp file. My guess is these headers already include parts of stb.