# Stbi loading errors

Tags: c++, stb-image

When I try to use stbi to load an image all I get is this error:

```
1>Renderer.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread(int)" (?stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread@@YAXH@Z) already defined in LoadFile.obj

1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread(int)" (?stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread@@YAXH@Z) already defined in LoadFile.obj

1>Shape.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread(int)" (?stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread@@YAXH@Z) already defined in LoadFile.obj

1>Texture.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread(int)" (?stbi__unpremultiply_on_load_thread@@YAXH@Z) already defined in LoadFile.obj
```

and I get about 180 of these errors for different functions.

I include the stbi in one header file and I use this define

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
```

Comment: Do you define `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` in every file that you `#include <stb_image.h>`, or just in one of your files?

Comment: "I include the header file in one file and I use this define": Is that one file a single `.cpp` file or is it itself a header file included in multiple other files?

Comment: @jjramsey I only `#include <stb_image.h>` in one file and only use the define in that same file.

Comment: @user17732522 It is a header file included in multiple files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double inclusion and headers only library stbi\_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348798/double-inclusion-and-headers-only-library-stbi-image) and https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158106/why-am-i-getting-these-errors-when-including-stb-image-h

Comment: You must include `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` in only one translation unit. Including it in a header that is included in multiple translation units doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple `.cpp` files that use the functions of `stb_image.h`, including `main.cpp`, put `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` in `main.cpp` before the header file that includes `stb_image.h`.

The structure will look like this:

**header1.h**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "some_header_file.h"
#include "stb_image.h"

void someFunction ();
```

**source1.cpp**

```cpp
#include "header1.h"

void someFunction ()
{
    ...
    // code line which uses functions in stb_image.h, e.g.
    unsigned char* IMGpixels = stbi_load(imgFile, &IMGwidth, &IMGheight, &IMGchannels, 4);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION // should define this before include stb_image.h, 
#include "header1.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    // code line which uses functions in stb_image.h, e.g.
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(texFilename, &texWidth, &texHeight, &colorChannels, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

Put this in `stb_image.cpp`